# MariaDB EVENT autoclear DB returns warning

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I got MariaDB version 10.3.27 where im trying to run EVENT which starts everyday at 1am for clearing some databases. but when I try to pass lines below, it return 1 warning, but Im not sure why....
Can someone please clarify this for me? Thanks

```
delimiter $$

CREATE EVENT AUTOCLEAR
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS (TIMESTAMP(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
  DO
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM ESP1 WHERE timestamp  < ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))) + 7200);
        DELETE FROM ESP2 WHERE timestamp  < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) + 7200);
        DELETE FROM ESP3 WHERE timestamp  < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) + 7200);
        DELETE FROM ESP3_1 WHERE timestamp  < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) + 7200);
    END$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: What is the warning message?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad. Didnt enabled scheduler and not know how to read warnings...

`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=ON`

fixed my problem